# Combined 301 Redirect www, https and subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have the htaccess lines below to redirect requests without www and https to https://www.domainname.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domainname.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,END]
```

Then, if there are no subdomain at the end of requested url, I redirect it to /subdomain with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteRule ^$ subdomain [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to combine these two rules?

Comment: Since you want to rewrite specifically to `/subdomain` in the one case, but to `/$1` in the other, I don't think it makes much sense to try and cram this into just one set of conditions & rule. But you can of course try and write it in a way, so that only one redirect will happen